# Passing variables in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm trying to pass a variable I read from my Firebase Database.

```
    func annotatemyMap() {

    let refx = Database.database().reference().child("child").child("child").child("child").child("LocX")
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let locX = snapshot.value as! Double
    })

    let refy = Database.database().reference().child("child").child("child").child("child").child("LocY")
    refy.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let LocY = snapshot.value as! Double
    })

    point.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(locX , locY)
    //REST OF MY FUNCTIONS CODE........

}
```

locX and locY in point.coordinate are nil. I understand why but I can't figure out how to pass locX and locY to point.coordinate.

Question: How do I pass the value (read from firebase) of loxX and locY to point.coordinate.

Comment: what is the point ?

Comment: declare LocX, LocY at the beginning of function. So that it can be accessible in point.coordinate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to nest calls or use completions

```
let refx = Database.database().reference().child("child").child("child").child("child").child("LocX")
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    let locX = snapshot.value as! Double

      let refy = Database.database().reference().child("child").child("child").child("child").child("LocY")
      refy.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
       let LocY = snapshot.value as! Double

         point.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(locX , locY)
        //REST OF MY FUNCTIONS CODE........

     })

})
```